# videoBG with particles.js

Tags: video, particles.js

I'm trying to use an HTML5 videoBG
together with either [particles.js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) or less likely using [particleground](https://jnicol.github.io/particleground/)

any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: video background in codepen: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK

Comment: What exactly is the problem?